# Local Ext for reflexive sheaves on surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a normal Gorenstein complex surface with $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for $i>0$ and $F$ be a rank one reflexive sheaf on $X$. I'm trying to find some ways to determine local Ext $\mathcal{E}xt^i_X(F,F)$.

For $i=0$, by the normality of $F$, I think we have $\mathcal{H}om_X(F,F)=\mathcal{O}_X$. Is there any similar result for $i>0$ (e.g. $\mathcal{E}xt^i_X(F,F)=0$ for $i>0$)?

The only thing now I can show is that $\mathcal{E}xt^i_X(F,F)$ is supported on points for $i>0$.

Comment: Perhaps you already know this: if $X$ is smooth, a coherent sheaf $F$is locally free if and only if $$\mathcal{Ext}^i(F, \, G)=0$$
for all $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $G$ and for all $i \geq 1$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi if $X$ is regular, then any reflexive sheaf of rank $1$ is locally free (so then the answer to the question is positive).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: but the OP is supposing $X$ normal Gorenstein, that is a bit less than regular (=smooth). For instance, it seems to me that the Weil divisor of a line in a quadric cone in $\mathbb{P}^3$ defines a rank 1 reflexive sheaf that is not locally free. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's right, I was just trying to say that your comment about the smooth case is not very relevant because the smooth case is trivial. I'm actually working out the very same example you're giving, because it also gives a counterexample to the question.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, note that formation of $\mathscr Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathscr F,\mathscr F)$ is local, so we don't need global assumptions such as $H^i(X,\mathcal O_X) = 0$ for $i > 0$.

Secondly, I agree that the natural map $\mathcal O_X \to \mathscr Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathscr F,\mathscr F)$ is an isomorphism whenever $\mathscr F$ is a rank $1$ reflexive sheaf on a normal (integral) Noetherian scheme $X$. Indeed, there exists an open $j \colon U \hookrightarrow X$ with $\operatorname{codim}(X\setminus U,X) \geq 2$ such that $j^*\mathscr F$ is locally free of rank $1$ and the unit $\mathscr F \to j_*j^*\mathscr F$ of the adjunction $j^* \dashv j_*$ is an isomorphism; see [Tag [0AY6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AY6)]. Then the natural map
$$\mathcal O_U \to \mathscr Hom_{\mathcal O_U}(j^*\mathscr F,j^*\mathscr F) = j^*\mathscr Hom_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathscr F,\mathscr F)$$
is an isomorphism, so the claim follows from [Tags [0AY4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AY4) and [0EBJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EBJ)].

But the higher vanishing does *not* hold:

**Example.** Let $k$ be a field, and let $R = k[x,y,z]/(z^2-xy)$ be the quadratic cone. Let $I = (x,z)$ be the ideal of the $y$-axis. We get a surjection $R^2 \to I$ by $(a,b) \mapsto ax-bz$, and write $K \subseteq R^2$ for the kernel. Then the second projection $\pi \colon K \to R$ is injective with image $I$: if $(a,0) \in K$, then $a = 0$ since $R$ is a domain, showing injectivity. The image of $\pi \colon K \to R$ is those $r \in R$ such that $rz \in (x)$, i.e. the annihilator of $z$ in $R/(x) \cong k[x,y,z]/(x,z^2)$. This is the ideal $I = (x,z)$. (Concretely, $K$ is generated by $(z,x)$ and $(y,z)$.) Thus we get a short exact sequence
$$0 \to I \to R^2 \to I \to 0,$$
which shows that $I$ is reflexive [Tag [0AV2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AV2)] (see also [Tag [0EBM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EBM)]). Applying $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,I)$ gives an exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,I) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(R^2,I) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,I) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_R(I,I) \to 0.$$
By the above, the first terms read
$$0 \to R \to I^2 \to R.$$
The final map cannot be surjective, for then $I$ would be projective: if $M$ is any $R$-module, then the short exact sequence $0 \to R \to I^2 \to R \to 0$ would give
$$0 = \operatorname{Ext}^i_R(R,M) \to \operatorname{Ext}^i_R(I^2,M) \to \operatorname{Ext}^i_R(R,M) = 0,$$
showing that $\operatorname{Ext}^i_R(I,M)^2 = 0$ for $i > 0$. This is absurd since $I$ is not a principal ideal. We conclude that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(I,I)$ cannot be zero. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I can say that finitely generated modules for which
$$R \to \mathrm{Hom}_R(M, M) \;\;\;\text{is an isomorphism, where $1 \mapsto id$}$$
and
$$\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,M) = 0 \;\;\;\text{ for $i > 0$}$$
are called *semi-dualizing modules* (if they are in $D^b_{coh}(R)$, they are called *semi-dualizing complexes*).
This can be more compactly written as
$$R \to {\bf R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(M, M)$$
is an isomorphism.
The point is that $M$ would be a dualizing/canonical module (respectively complex) if it had finite injective dimension.

There's actually a lot of work on identifying semi-dualizing modules/complexes, and they are relatively rare.  For a Gorenstein local ring $R$, the *only* semi-dualizing module is $R$ itself up to isomorphism (in fact, the only semi-dualizing complex is $R$ up to shift).  See Corollary 8.6 in
[Christensen, Semi-dualizing complexes and their Auslander categories](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-05/S0002-9947-01-02627-7/S0002-9947-01-02627-7.pdf).  For a Gorenstein variety, it follows that the only semi-dualizing modules are line bundles.

If you weaken the condition of Gorenstein to Cohen-Macaulay, then there can be more.  If I recall correctly, there are still only finitely many, and there's an even number (see [Christensen-Wagstaff](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2734)).  In fact, unless things have changed in the past few years, no one knows an example where the number of semi-dualizing modules/complexes is not $2^n$ for some $n$.

I also found this somewhat older survey of semi-dualizing modules by Sather-Wagstaff:
[Semidualizing modules](https://ssather.people.clemson.edu/DOCS/sdm.pdf).